# Regex to validate checkbox input

Tags: php, regex, validation, checkbox, boolean

I'm having some issues with codeigniter's validation filter when using checkboxes. I typically used the `numeric` filter for checkboxes, presuming it would filter for `0` or `1` but now I see there are several instances in which this fails.

Does anyone know a regex that I can put in the `preg_match` to validate a checkbox?

I would like this to allow for booleans and a few others `1`, `0`, `null`, `true`, `false`, empty etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkbox only returns one value. It's value (as indicated in its `value=` attribute) or 'true'. If the checkbox is not selected, it is not passed in the POST request. Therefore, for validation, you only need to check for 2 things:

1. Was it even selected in the first place?
2. Is its value consistent with what you expect it to be?

So:

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']) && ($_POST['checkbox'] == 'true') { //or whatever value you want
```

Should do the trick nicely. Unless I've misunderstood your question in which case please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes either have a value or they don't.  If they have a value they're checked, if they don't then they're not checked.

A regex would be serious overkill here, you only need to check if the checkbox exists in the submitted data.

```
$checkBoxChecked = isset ($_POST['checkbox_name_goes_here']);
```